# VSTS/VSO HOWTO add a field that is available in Bug, Task, Backlogitem,

Tags: alm

In VSTS I want to add a field that is available in any type of WIP, like f.e. state is. Is this feasable ? How to do that ?

The idea is to have a SubState field that better defines the actual state of an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a custom field in VSTS. Basically, you add a new Field for one WIT, and then enable it to be shown in a layout for the others. Picklist might be a good idea, if you want predefined list of allowed values.

See detailed howto [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/customize-process-field#pick-list). But adding a new field will not automatically have a full workflow support - like updating related fields when the "new" one is changed, for example.

So, - consider [customizing board](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/kanban/add-columns) instead of adding a new Field, this is much easier and fits for the most of cases.

Comment: Can you use these extra columns in queries ? If so how ?

Comment: After you create a filed you can use it in queries just as any other standard field. It even appears in field selection drop-down, when you create query in Team Web Access.

Comment: Customizing board seems to be different from adding fields. The query question was about the added column on the board.